# What is the difference between std::shared_ptr and std::atomic<std::shared_ptr> aka. std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, atomic, smart-pointers

I've read the [following](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/why-do-we-need-atomic_shared_ptr.html) article by *Antony Williams* and as I understood, in addition to the atomic shared count in `std::shared_ptr`, in `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` (in the article, known as `std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr`) the actual pointer to the shared object is also atomic.

But when I read about reference-counted version of `lock_free_stack` described in Antony's book about [C++ Concurrency](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) it seems for me that the same aplies also for `std::shared_ptr`, because functions like `std::atomic_load`, `std::atomic_compare_exchnage_weak` are applied to the instances of `std::shared_ptr`.

```
template <class T>
class lock_free_stack
{
public:
  void push(const T& data)
  {
    const std::shared_ptr<node> new_node = std::make_shared<node>(data);
    new_node->next = std::atomic_load(&head_);
    while (!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head_, &new_node->next, new_node));
  }

  std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
  {
    std::shared_ptr<node> old_head = std::atomic_load(&head_);
    while(old_head &&
          !std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head_, &old_head, old_head->next));
    return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
  }

private:
  struct node
  {
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
    std::shared_ptr<node> next;

    node(const T& data_) : data(std::make_shared<T>(data_)) {}
  };

private:
  std::shared_ptr<node> head_;
};
```

What is the exact difference between these two types of smart pointers? If the pointer in a `std::shared_ptr` instance is not atomic, why it is possible write the above lock-free stack implementation?

Comment: It's not lock free. Typical implementations of `atomic_*` use a global array of mutexes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The atomic "thing" in `shared_ptr` is not the shared pointer itself, but the control block it points to. meaning that as long as you don't mutate the `shared_ptr` across multiple threads, you are ok. do note that *copying* a `shared_ptr` only mutates the control block, and not the `shared_ptr` itself.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(4);
for (auto i =0;i<10;i++){
   std::thread([ptr]{ auto copy = ptr; }).detach(); //ok, only mutates the control block 
}
```

Mutating the shared pointer itself, such as assigning it different values from multiple threads, is a data race, for example:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(4);
std::thread threadA([&ptr]{
   ptr = std::make_shared<int>(10);
});
std::thread threadB([&ptr]{
   ptr = std::make_shared<int>(20);
});
```

Here, we are mutating the control block (which is ok) but also the shared pointer itself, by making it point to a different values from multiple threads. This is not ok.

A solution to that problem is to wrap the `shared_ptr` with a lock, but this solution is not so scalable under some contention, and in a sense, loses the automatic feeling of the standard shared pointer.

Another solution is to use the standard functions you quoted, such as `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak`. This makes the work of synchronizing shared pointers a manual one, which we don't like.

This is where atomic shared pointer comes to play. You can mutate the shared pointer from multiple threads without fearing a data race and without using any locks. The standalone functions will be members ones, and their use will be much more natural for the user. This kind of pointer is extremely useful for lock-free data structures.

Comment: 10x for the answer but I don't understand how the functions as `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak` work correctly on instances of `std::shared_ptr`, after `std::shared_ptr` itself is not atomic and are they except more inconvenient, also somehow slower than methods of `std::atomic_shared_ptr`?

Comment: "atomic" is a convenience wrapper around reader-writer memory fences supplied by the CPU. declaring a type as "atomic" is just one way of making something atomic.

Comment: @bobeff Both libstdc++ and libc++ use a global fixed-size hash table of mutexes (!) to implement these operations on top of a non-atomic `shared_ptr`. They hash the address of the `shared_ptr` object to select one of the mutexes, lock it, then perform non-atomic operations.

Comment: vc++ does it even worse by just using one global lock

Comment: Why someone wants to use a shared_ptr atomically? The whole purpose of shared_ptr is multiple copies shared the ownership. Isn't it?

Comment: For example, if you implement a lock free list, then the "head" member can std::atomic_shared_ptr, this way you can push new nodes to the list in a thread-safe manner without resorting to using locks.

Answer (score 7):

[N4162](http://wg21.link/n4162)<sub><sup>(pdf)</sup></sub>, the proposal for atomic smart pointers, has a good explanation. Here's a quote of the relevant part:

> **Consistency**. As far as I know, the [util.smartptr.shared.atomic]
>   functions are the only atomic operations in the standard that 
>   are not available via an `atomic` type. And for all types 
>   besides  `shared_ptr`, we teach programmers to use atomic types 
>   in C++, not  `atomic_*` C-style functions. And that’s in part because of...
>
> **Correctness**. Using the free functions makes code error-prone
>   and racy by default. It is far superior to write `atomic` once on
>   the variable declaration itself and know all accesses
>   will be atomic, instead of having to remember to use the `atomic_*`
>   operation on *every* use of the object, even apparently-plain reads.
>   The latter style is error-prone; for example, “doing it wrong” means
>   simply writing whitespace (e.g., `head` instead of `atomic_load(&head)` ),
>   so that in this style every use of the variable is “wrong by default.” If you forget to
>   write the `atomic_*` call in even one place, your code will still
>   successfully compile without any errors or warnings, it will “appear
>   to work” including likely pass most testing, but will still contain a 
>   silent race with undefined behavior that usually surfaces as intermittent
>   hard-to-reproduce failures, often/usually in the field,
>   and I expect also in some cases exploitable vulnerabilities. 
>   These classes of errors are eliminated by simply declaring the variable `atomic`,
>   because then it’s safe by default and to write the same set of 
>   bugs requires explicit non-whitespace code (sometimes explicit 
>   `memory_order_*` arguments, and usually `reinterpret_cast`ing).
>
> **Performance**. `atomic_shared_ptr<>` as a distinct type
>   has an important efficiency advantage over the 
>   functions in [util.smartptr.shared.atomic] — it can simply store an
>   additional `atomic_flag` (or similar) for the internal spinlock 
>   as usual for `atomic<bigstruct>`. In contrast, the existing standalone functions 
>   are required to be usable on any arbitrary `shared_ptr`
>   object, even though the vast majority of `shared_ptr`s will
>   never be used atomically. This makes the free functions inherently 
>   less efficient; for example, the implementation could require 
>   every `shared_ptr` to carry the overhead of an internal spinlock
>   variable (better concurrency, but significant overhead per 
>   `shared_ptr`), or else the library must  maintain a lookaside data
>   structure to store the extra information for `shared_ptr`s that are
>   actually used atomically, or (worst and apparently common in
>   practice) the library must use a global spinlock.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `std::atomic_load()` or `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak()` on a `shared_ptr` is functionally equivalent to calling `atomic_shared_ptr::load()` or `atomic_shared_ptr::atomic_compare_exchange_weak()`. There shouldn't be any performance difference between the two. Calling `std::atomic_load()` or `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak()` on a `atomic_shared_ptr` would be syntactically redundant and might or might not incur a performance penalty.

Answer (score 4):

[`atomic_shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr) is an API refinement. `shared_ptr` already supports atomic operations, but only when using the appropriate [atomic non-member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). This is error-prone, because the non-atomic operations remain available and are too easy for an unwary programmer to invoke by accident. `atomic_shared_ptr` is less error-prone because it doesn't expose any non-atomic operations.

`shared_ptr` and `atomic_shared_ptr` expose different APIs, but they don't necessarily need to be implemented differently; `shared_ptr` already supports all the operations exposed by `atomic_shared_ptr`. Having said that, the atomic operations of `shared_ptr` are not as efficient as they could be, because it must also support non-atomic operations. Therefore there are performance reasons why `atomic_shared_ptr` could be implemented differently. This is related to the single responsibility principle. "An entity with several disparate purposes... often offers crippled interfaces for any of its specific purposes because the partial overlap among various areas of functionality blurs the vision needed for crisply implementing each." (Sutter & Alexandrescu 2005, *C++ Coding Standards*)

Comment: "there is no reason for their internals to be implemented differently." There is, though. `atomic_shared_ptr` can carry a synchronization primitive with it. If you do that with `shared_ptr` you'll be pessimizing the vast majority of uses which don't need atomic access.