# Are Rust smart pointers std::rc::Rc and std::sync::Arc analogous to the C++ smart pointers std::shared_ptr and std::atomic_shared_ptr respectively?

Tags: c++, rust, smart-pointers

Is there analogy between Rust smart pointers `std::rc::Rc` and `std::sync::Arc` with the C++ smart pointers `std::shared_ptr` and `std::atomic_shared_ptr`? For me, they look the same, but probably there are some implementation nuances. For example in C++ `std::shared_ptr` the reference count in the control block is atomic despite the pointer itself is not. Is it the same in Rust's `std::rc::Rc`?

Comment: It doesn't look like `atomic_shared_ptr` was ever made part of `std`; it [lived in `experimental`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr) until it was [standardized as a specialization of `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2). Does that help answer the question or would you like to rephrase it in light of this fact?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Rust's `Arc<T>` is largely equivalent to C++'s `shared_ptr<T>`

Both are "smart pointers" that provide shared ownership of a value via reference counting. They both use atomics for internal operations so that ownership can be tracked between threads safely.

One notable difference is the C++ `std::shared_ptr` implementation provides an *aliasing constructor* where you can create a `std::shared_ptr<U>` for a nested field of a `std::shared_ptr<T>` such that the `std::shared_ptr<U>` tracks the root `T` object properly.

#### C++ has no equivalent of Rust's `Rc<T>`

The only difference between `std::rc::Rc` and `std::sync::Arc` is that the internal reference tracking is not atomic. This means it cannot be used between threads, but has the benefit of avoiding the potential costs of atomic operations.

#### Rust has no equivalent of C++'s `atomic<shared_ptr<T>>`

C++'s `std::atomic` is generic so its atomic pointer type is a `std::atomic<T*>` whereas Rust's just has the dedicated type `std::sync::atomic::AtomicPtr<T>`. C++ has a specialization for `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` so that multiple threads can atomically access and modify the `shared_ptr` itself, not just the shared value. The `std::atomic_shared_ptr` mentioned by OP was not standardized in favor of this specialization.

<sup>There may exist *libraries* for the equivalents but I've only included what's in the respective standard libraries.</sup>

See also:

- [What is the Rust equivalent of C++'s shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834414/what-is-the-rust-equivalent-of-cs-shared-ptr)
- [What is the difference between std::shared_ptr and std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223599/what-is-the-difference-between-stdshared-ptr-and-stdexperimentalatomic-sha)

Comment: When considering whether Rust has an "equivalent" of `atomic<shared_ptr<T>>`, it may be worth noting that `atomic<shared_ptr<T>>` exists on every platform, but is not guaranteed to be lock-free, while [`AtomicPtr<T>` is always lock-free, but not guaranteed to exist on every platform](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicPtr.html). There is a crate (`atomic` IIRC) that provides an `Atomic<T>` type constructor with C++-like semantics.

Comment: @trentcl I could be here all day recounting the things like "`shared_ptr<T>` is safe between threads but that doesn't mean `T` is safe between threads whereas Rust's type system ensures that", or C++ has *these* functions but Rust has *these*, or mentioning as you have about how the standard library chooses to provide cross-platform support. I tried my best to give a big picture overview of the differences since that seemed to be the focus of the question.

Comment: Understood. My comment wasn't meant as a criticism of your answer (or of C++), more "fun fact" than anything.

Answer (score 2):

> For example in C++ std::shared_ptr the reference count in the control block is atomic despite the pointer itself is not. Is it the same in Rust's std::rc::Rc?

No. `Arc` is the analogue to `shared_ptr`: the reference-counting is atomic (and thus thread-safe), the data is not (which is why you'll usually see `Arc<Mutex<T>>` or `Arc<RwLock<T>>` in order to allow mutation of the inner type, otherwise `Arc` will only provide read-only access).

`Rc` is completely unsynchronised, and in fact statically can not be moved between threads (it's [`!Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html)). There is no such type in the C++ standard library[0].

[0] although libstdc++ will use non-thread-safe `shared_ptr` if it believes multithreading is not involved, that's more of an optimisation / hack: https://snf.github.io/2019/02/13/shared-ptr-optimization/