# atomic smart pointers and mutex in C++20

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex, c++20

If I want to write/read to an object from multiple threads I have to use an additional mutex for thread safety even if I use shared_pointer in C++11. Does this still apply if I use atomic_shared_pointer introduced in C++20?

Greetings

Comment: Any help: [What is the difference between std::shared_ptr and std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223599/what-is-the-difference-between-stdshared-ptr-and-stdexperimentalatomic-sha)

Comment: If you are modifying the object the `shared_ptr` points to, then yes.  `shared_ptr` only protects itself.

Answer (score 7):

There are three layers one might consider when thinking about the atomicity of `shared_ptr`.

1. Atomicity of the reference count. That is, you have two `shared_ptr` objects on different threads, but they both access the same managed reference count. What happens when you copy one `shared_ptr` on one thread and delete a different `shared_ptr` that references the same reference count?

   `shared_ptr` provides a guarantee against race conditions in these cases. Data races on the reference count for different instances of a `shared_ptr` never happen.
2. Atomicity of the `shared_ptr` object itself. That is, you have *one* `shared_ptr` object which is *referenced* by different threads. One thread may want to replace the `shared_ptr`'s stored object or something, but someone else may be accessing it at that moment.

   C++20's `atomic<shared_ptr>` deals with this case. If the object is an `atomic<shared_ptr>`, then you can play these games through the usual `atomic` interface. C++11 has [a number of atomic accessor functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) that can achieve the same effects, so long as all code uses those accessors.
3. Atomicity of the thing *pointed to* by a `shared_ptr`. In this case, multiple threads may be using multiple different `shared_ptr` objects, but all of these `shared_ptr` objects point to the same object. And those threads want to access the object being pointed to by them.

   This atomicity is *all on you*. `shared_ptr`'s atomicity guarantees are about accesses to the *pointer*, not what it points to. If you need synchronized access to what is being pointed to, you will have to build that yourself.