# Could std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<Struct Demo>> could be safely used with C++11 since the said partial specializations is only available with C++20?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, atomic, shared-ptr

As per the [std::atomic article on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), which says that (emphasis mine):

> Defined in header `<atomic>`
>
> ```cpp
> template< class T >
> struct atomic; // (since C++11)
> ```
>
> ```cpp
> template< class U >
> struct atomic<U*>; // (since C++11)
> ```
>
> Defined in header `<memory>`
>
> ```cpp
> template< class U >
> struct atomic<std::shared_ptr<U>>; // (since C++20)
> ```
>
> ```cpp
> template< class U >
> struct atomic<std::weak_ptr<U>>; // (since C++20)
> ```

Even though the partial specializations for `std::shared<T>` are only available with C++20, could `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<Struct Demo>>` be safely used with C++11?

Is there any potential problem that I should be aware of?

Comment: `T` must be trivially copyable, which `shared_ptr` is not.

Comment: @RaymondChen Could you please tell me where you see such requirement?  I really can't  see any hint in [std::atomic by cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

Comment: "The program is ill-formed if any of following values is false: `std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value`..."

Answer (score 1):

No, the primary template for `std::atomic<T>` requires `T` to be trivially-copyable, which `std::shared_ptr` is not.

Trying to use it before C++20 will fail to compile.

Comment: Indeed, https://godbolt.org/z/1qjGahheG shows g++13 and clang++17 `-stdlib=libc++` erroring for that reason if you don't use `-std=gnu++20` or later (or `-std=c++20`).  So even in practice, current standard-library headers that have the specialization don't enable it unless you set a C++ version recent enough to require it.  (And the question about "potential problems" is moot since it doesn't even compile, unless there is some compiler that's different.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, per standard (prior to C++20) instantiating that specialization would make the program ill-formed, implying that a diagnostic is mandatory and in practice meaning that compilers will error out on compilation. A conforming compiler could support it in pre-C++20 mode, but would have to at least warn the user about the use and then the behavior would be completely up to the implementation. So even then answering whether it is "safe" in general is pointless.

Comment: @Peter Cordes C++14 also does not work for the said sense? *In C++14, the requirement for the underlying type T of std::atomic<T> to be trivially copyable was relaxed.*

  *Starting from C++14, std::atomic supports non-trivially copyable types as long as they meet certain requirements. The underlying type T must be both copyable and assignable, meaning it must have a copy constructor and an assignment operator defined.*

Comment: @John: You could have just tried it yourself by editing the command-line args on the Godbolt link.  But no, https://godbolt.org/z/s67jjfb6G shows that `-std=gnu++14` doesn't change anything.  The actual error message is that it's not trivially-copyable; if they support non-trivially-copyable types, presumably there's a separate specialization or check that already failed.

Comment: @John No idea where you got that quote from, but it is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` would be a constraint violation because according to [[atomics.types.generic] p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/atomics.types.generic#1):

> The type of the template argument `T` shall be trivially copyable ([[basic.types]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types))

*Note: this requirement was made even stricter in C++20 ([[atomics.types.generic.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/atomics.types.generic.general)) through [LWG3012: `atomic<T>` is unimplementable for non-`is_trivially_copy_constructible` `T`](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3012), but it doesn't apply to the partial specialization for smart pointers ([[util.smartptr.atomic]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/util.smartptr.atomic)).*

`std::shared_ptr` isn't trivially copyable, so it cannot be used with `std::atomic`.

However, [`std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<T>>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) is just an API refinement. Prior to C++20, you can use the utility functions such as [`std::atomic_load(const std::shared_ptr*)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). For example:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<int> value = std::atomic_load(&my_pointer);
// or, with explicit memory order
std::shared_ptr<int> value = std::atomic_load_explicit(&my_pointer, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

*See also: [What is the difference between std::shared_ptr and std::atomic<std::shared_ptr> aka. std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40223599/5740428)*