# Is it safe to use std::shared_ptr between productor and consumer when the shared managed object would never be acessed at the same time?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, c++14, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Here is the demo code snippet below.
Could the `mutex` be removed since `std::shared_ptr` itself is thread-safe and the managed object would never be accessed by productor and consumer at the same time?

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

struct Demo {
    int i;
    float f;
};

using SCDemoPtr = std::shared_ptr<Demo>;

class ResultManager {
public:
    ResultManager();
    void SetFrontRes(SCDemoPtr oms_result);
    void SetBackRes(SCDemoPtr oms_result);
    void MergeResults();

private:
    std::mutex front_mutex;
    std::mutex back_mutex;
    SCDemoPtr front_result;
    SCDemoPtr back_result;
};

ResultManager::ResultManager() {}

void ResultManager::SetFrontRes(SCDemoPtr oms_res) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(front_mutex);
    front_result = oms_res;
}

void ResultManager::SetBackRes(SCDemoPtr oms_res) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(back_mutex);
    back_result = oms_res;
}

void ResultManager::MergeResults() {
    SCDemoPtr cur_front_res;
    SCDemoPtr cur_back_res;

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(front_mutex);
        cur_front_res = front_result;
    }

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(back_mutex);
        cur_back_res = back_result;
    }

    if (cur_front_res == nullptr || cur_back_res == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    SCDemoPtr merge_res(new Demo);
    merge_res->i = cur_front_res->i + cur_back_res->i;
}

int main() {
    ResultManager res_manager;

    std::thread producer1([&res_manager]() {
        while (true) {
            SCDemoPtr res(new Demo);
            res->i = 1;
            res->f = 3.14;
            res_manager.SetFrontRes(res);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    });

    std::thread producer2([&res_manager]() {
        while (true) {
            SCDemoPtr res(new Demo);
            res->i = 1;
            res->f = 3.14;
            res_manager.SetBackRes(res);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    });

    while (true) {
        res_manager.MergeResults();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    producer1.join();
    producer2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Could the mutex be removed since std::shared_ptr itself is thread-safe

No, access to the `std::shared_ptr` itself is *not* thread-safe and doesn't behave any different than access to any other object. Trying to modify it while another thread tries to access it is a data race and causes undefined behavior.

The *only* thing that is thread-safe with a `std::shared_ptr` is the lifetime of the managed object, which is guaranteed to be destroyed by exactly one thread.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I still have a quetion about your answer. I think even if  `MergeResults()` get the lock before `producer`1 and `producer2`, it will not ry to dereference a empty shared pointer(i.e. nullptr) because if `(cur_front_res == nullptr || cur_back_res == nullptr)` is satisfied, the function would returns immediately. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: @John Oh yes. Sorry, I must have overlooked that line.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not be safe. You are conflating thread-safety at different levels:

1. The thread-safety of the pointed-to object. This would be ensured by `std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<T>>`. (Not your case)
2. The thread-safety of the reference counter. This is ensured by any `std::shared_ptr<T>`. This allows you to have multiple threads use *separate* `std::shared_ptr<T>` objects that own the same `T` concurrently. (Not your case)
3. The thread-safety of the smart pointer itself. This is ensured by [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2), or a `std::shared_ptr` with a `std::mutex` guarding it. (Your case)

You are reading `back_result` in one place using`cur_back_res = back_result;` and writing to it in another place with `back_result = oms_res;`. This is only thread-safe because you're ensuring mutual exclusion. If you removed the mutex, you would have a data race.

You're using C++14, so the [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) specializations are not available to you, but you can use the old utility free functions for atomic operations:

```cpp
// atomically load from a std::shared_ptr
cur_back_result = std::atomic_load(&back_result);

// atomically store to a std::shared_ptr
std::atomic_store(&back_result, &oms_res);
```

If you use these functions, you no longer need a mutex to guard the `std::shared_ptr`.

*Note: the `explicit` versions of these functions also let you specify a memory order. See [What do each memory_order mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12346487/5740428) if you're unfamiliar with this topic.*

*See also: [What is the difference between std::shared_ptr and std::atomic<std::shared_ptr> aka. std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40223599/5740428)*

Comment: ***The thread-safety of the pointed-to object***?How to understand that in the right way? As far as know, the object managed by shared pointer should be protected if it read/write by two or more threads.

Comment: @John yes, it should be. `std::shared_ptr` doesn't ensure thread-safety of whatever is being pointed to, it just thread-safely counts references to it. I've just listed this point for completeness, since there's three different levels at which thread-safety may have to be ensured.